# What is the dietary term for someone who eats meat but not eggs or milk?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I was wondering what you call someone who essentially still eats meat but **doesn't**
eat products from animals like eggs and milk etc.. Would it be a non lacto-ova non vegetarian.

Answer (score 2):

This practice is more common than most think.  While there are many reasons for not eating dairy, yet consuming meat, the most common I have come across would be that once people learn that milk (dairy) comes from cows who have given birth (a lot of people do not put 2 and 2 together), they reject dairy on a clean conscience principle, as that milk should be for the calf not human consumption.  There are also the individuals who are lactose intolerant.  The same mentality stands for eggs, as eggs are technically chicks or chicken periods.  However, most eggs sold for human consumption are unfertilized.  But I digress.  Essentially, the only term I have come across for this lifestyle diet is meatatarian.
I follow this lifestyle diet, but always just explain I do not eat dairy, but I do eat eggs and meat (and obviously vegetables, fruits, beans... etc.).

Answer (score 0):

After thinking about it a bit, I'd say the word is simply **carnivore** and we can use the adjective **strict** as we do with **vegetarian**:

> He's a *strict carnivore*.

He doesn't eat eggs or dairy.  He probably doesn't eat fruits, nuts, or grains either, except as found in the digestive tracts of the beasts he devours.

Comment: I don't think this really matches the answer. In addition to the objection that OP didn't say anything about fruit or vegetables or whatever, because being a proper strict *carnivore* in the same way that some people are vegans is so unlikely (and maybe impossible), the term "carnivore" is almost exclusively a figurative term for someone who prefers meat (and I would even say other protein-rich foods like cheese, milk and eggs) over food made from plants. It doesn't really get across the intended meaning.

Comment: I'm not being totally serious, Paul. There is no single hyphenated term for this. We'd need to  formulate a phrase.

Comment: The term "carnivore" isn't on the same scale as "vegan". Carnivore/omnivore/herbivore describes what a species has evolved the ability to eat/digest , while vegan/vegetarian describes what they actually eat. ie. humans are omnivores, regardless of what they actually eat.

Answer (score 0):

I would describe them as ovo-lactose-free, in the same way that someone may be described as gluten-free.

Comment: Hi Donna, welcome to ELL. People might refer to others as being gluten- or ovo-lactose-free, but those are technically terms for their diet, not the consumers.

Comment: Thanks Joachim - yes, goes back to Niall's comment, I think. 

In common usage, people describe themselves as vegan or vegetarian, and this frequently describes their lifestyle and identity, i.e., not wearing clothing or using other items made of animal products.